# Ph.D. rejection from German University due to citizenship and gotten degree from my previous institute by BAFA

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, germany, physics

This spring I ran away from Russia due to increasing repressions and other risks. Long story short, I got a Ph.D. position in quantum computing at Stuttgart University in the state of Baden-Württemberg. I was told to be in Germany at the 1st of June to sign my contract and start my Ph.D., but after my arrival university staff notified me that I am under check up by BAFA (an organisation dealing with export). After 3 months I was rejected from the promising position. Arguments were that I could be a spy and also could steal important knowledge from the university.

I also recently was told that even the fact that I studied in Russia is a problem. As far as I know I am the first such case, I've asked people that got a degree from my university (Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology) and all of them are doing fine in Germany.
I've heard people from China and India sometimes face such problems. I would like to know if anyone is familiar with  my case and if there is some solution to it or what organization I could ask for help.
Because the decision was made after 3 months in September. I don't have enough time to get an employment contract in another Ph.D. program. I spend almost all my money only to get to Germany and now I really don't know what to do.

UPD1: Thanks everyone who sent their support and gave me advice.

UPD2: If you would like to blame me for the war, because I am russian and I deserve everything what is happening to me, please, do not do it here, do it there lonelyhorse04@gmail.com, it is my email.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139975/discussion-on-question-by-evgenii-gadylshin-ph-d-rejection-from-german-universi).

Comment: I vote to close this question because it depends too much on personal details, as you state "all other people are doing fine in Germany".

Comment: @EarlGrey I wrote " I've asked people that got a degree from my university (Moscow Institute of Physics and Technology) and all of them are doing fine in Germany", not all other people. The meaning of this sentence that people that I know did not face any legal problems with employment. It is just my observation.

Comment: @Evgenii Are you elegible for Ukrainian citizenship? Because that would make things  much easier in terms of migration, you would not need a visa to move inside the Schengen area and find a job (still security suspicions would be there) but you could work on other areas to support yourself, or have time to find another PhD position.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I need to ask an Ukrainian lawyer, but I think I could. Problem is this procedure takes more than 1 year. Not only my citizenship is a problem but also the fact that I study in russian university. Also, I was told that people from post soviet space will have problems with employment in cutting edge research if they have degree from russian education facility.

Comment: @Evgenii I only comment about citizenship due to easing of migration rules, Ukrainians have visa-free access to the Schengen area, and more chances to get work permits. I do not comment on rumors or "I was told" because these could be not true and it all depends on where (institute/uni) and what (topic, environment), this is something key, it is still possibly for you to find PhD positions or a job to support yourself, apply, do not assume the blanket ban that some of the answers are implying. Know the local system and you will have no trouble finding a job. Just try to be flexible.

Comment: Please check this meta-question 

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383800/what-about-sensitive-details-being-retained-in-the-chat-and-related-things

for a serious issue about (poor) SE handling of personal informations. The issue is of big concern in relationship to this question.

Comment: @EarlGrey OP is clearly forgoing the safest route here, and it might seem unwise, but it is a valid choice still. Arguably, a retaliation resulting from an over-exposure of personal information on SE is overall unlikely, and the best practices are in place to prevent the "it would be really dumb if a reckless post on the internet ends one's career". OSINT does not seem like a serious threat model here, and if you are concerned about a targeted, state-based action taken (also seems unlikely), OP is probably more vulnerable to it because of other sources of information.

Comment: @Lodinn "The Department of Homeland Security says it's necessary to combat crimes like terrorism and child pornography." (from https://www.cbc.ca/news/science/usa-border-phones-search-1.4494371 yes, sure, against terrorists, which on average are the people with political opinion differing from the ruling elite).
I am a pessimist and I prefer to err on the safe side.  Much of my understanding of surveillance in the modern era comes from Eugeny Morozov, "the political dissenter that sold out to the US" (citation of someone, I do not know whom, but I am sure it has been and it will be said) .

Comment: @EarlGrey And that is a valid choice, too. People in Russia and Belarus are getting jail time for social media posts, phone searches are basically a given; it is not even that much of surrendering privacy anymore if some other state decides to do the same. If we are talking DHS, right there is the Gmail account one must assume DHS has access to should they want it. But all that said, it is not entirely unreasonable to expect to win some battles by being consistent and at least a little bit open about your stance. Picking these battles is important, however.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lengthy discussion in the comments already, and I hope people more familiar with the German side of things have sufficiently elaborated on that.

I would instead try to offer you an analysis from the perspective of someone still planning the move.

You have a pool of resources available to you and a bunch of liabilities. Your biggest liabilities are:

1. Money. You need money to survive, at the end of the day, and will need to sort it out somehow. From your post, you do not have much left and spending an year or two on tropical island vacation arranging your next position is understandably not on the list.
2. Legal status/background. Goes without saying.
3. Poor social capital. You do not seem to have a strong network, especially outside of Russia. Your research profile is okay, but not stellar.
4. Doing anything outside of continuing research is clearly not optimal in the long run, but you might need to make concessions as you go.

Your main recourse lies in whatever reputable contacts you do have and in what skills you demonstrably have. In this case, it seems like the professor has jumped the gun and decided to avoid any potential complications - after all, they have not that much to gain and a lot to lose. That you have not managed to make a convincing case in over 4 months since the date your contract was supposed to start is hugely problematic. I am afraid convincing the university to reverse the decision *within a week* is, essentially, an impossible task.

Given the visa expiration date, your immediate next step would be either moving somewhere else for the time being (this may prove impossible due to money issues), applying for the asylum or getting stuck in the legal limbo. Like @Dr.Snoopy points out, you could, in theory, live in Germany without having the paperwork and try to find employment, but this is also problematic for obvious reasons. I would advice at least consider applying for the asylum: that way your stay will be legal while your application is being considered (of course, it is not of much help if you get a desk reject the very next day).

Another immediate action is contacting whoever you believe could support you one way or another - your advisor and colleagues are probably your first option here when it comes to job seeking, but pursue as many leads as you possibly can at once.

Finally, have a plan of action for when things go wrong and do not put all eggs in one basket (I guess you have learned that lesson the hard way). Your current situation is fairly bad, so adjust your expectations accordingly - it will give you a different perspective on your options.

It is soul crushing to have a bright future taken away from you by something you did not really have influence over, but, IMHO, it is better to view your circumstances pessimistically and be ready to work hard and build your career from the ground up. On the plus side, you do not have to leave behind some 20+ years of your work.

I sincerely hope you will be able to turn it around.

UPD: Things seem to get increasingly complicated with respect to being able to move outside of Russia once you are here. Treat the returning option as your very last resort, and maybe not even that.

Comment: I think this answer misses the point a little: The problem is the field of study, especially after [this](https://correctiv.org/aktuelles/wirtschaft/2022/05/18/wie-deutschlands-wissenschaft-china-hilft-zur-militaer-supermacht-aufzusteigen/) became public, German universities have probably become more cautious. I guess the primary decision OP has to make is if it is more important to get out (stay out) of Russia or to do a PhD in that specific area.

Comment: @erc You sum it up pretty well - IMHO, they have several options: either find some country more willing to go ahead with them pursuing it (China would be the most obvious option here but given the context, they might get a measure of personal comfort but there are obvious problems with this decision; oddly, USA might be more receptive also), be willing to sacrifice their field of study (likely the least contentious), or go back to Russia (the worst option for OP).

Comment: But the reason I'm "missing the point" here is that assuming for a moment OP is willing to not pursue their chosen academic track for a while or even at all - and I'd argue they should be definitely considering this - it still leaves them with a logistical nightmare *right now*. They thought they had a job lined up for them and now are in a foreign country without money, documents or job prospects. They don't have the luxury of mulling over decades-spanning decisions and must focus on making ends meet first.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to hear about the situation you are in. I have been hesitant to post an answer as it's not really a clear-cut solution to your question. However, since I realized that in the current situation there is probably nobody who can give you a definite solution I'll give it a shot and hope that it helps you and others in your situation.

I can imagine a few options to explore, I'll try to outline what I know about them and where you can get more information. I'll assume that you are located in our near Stuttgart- if not, you can find similar organisations in all major German cities.

**1. Immediate help:**

I don't know how much money or time on your visa/residence permit you have left. If your situation is desperate and a return to Russia is impossible you really might want to think about whether you will apply for refugee status or not (as already mentioned by other posters). From your description I got the feeling that this is not what you are aiming for, but if your only alternative is living under a bridge, this might be an option. If you go this route I suggest to open another topic in a different stack to get more information.

- If you are not yet sure what to do this contact might be helpful (in German): https://www.elk-wue.de/helfen/fluechtlinge-und-migranten/asylpfarramt
  Short summary: It's an offer by the Protestant church aimed at everybody who seeks advice for (im)migration topics. They explicitly mention that they also offer guidance to illegal immigrants who have no other place to go; I therefore assume that you will be able to have an "unofficial" chat exploring options for immediate help.
- Side-note: How Germany will behave with respect to Russian refugees is not yet clear. Information in German and English (by Pro Asyl, a well-known association fighting for rights of refugees; I have not managed to find a more "official" source): https://www.proasyl.de/news/flucht-aus-russland-was-wir-aktuell-sagen-koennen/
  They also offer advice (in English): https://www.proasyl.de/en/pro-asyl-advice-in-individual-cases/
- I was hesitant to post this, as not everybody is religious and I cannot offer any experience on their political stance, but then I thought it's up to you to decide whether it's interesting for you. The Russian parish in Stuttgart ([contact details in German](http://www.rok-stuttgart.de/index.php/de/impressum.html)) consists of Ukrainians and Russians who, according to [this interview (in German)](https://www.swr.de/swraktuell/baden-wuerttemberg/stuttgart/russisch-orthodoxe-kirche-stuttgart-und-der-krieg-talk-limberger-100.html) try to master the crisis together.

If you have a bit more time and money left, you might find the following information interesting:

**2. Official German job portal aimed at Russian immigrants**:

Not specifically aimed at academia, but there exists a special program by the German federal government for recruiting qualified Russian immigrants who are leaving their homeland due to the current situation. Information in [German](https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/themen/krieg-in-der-ukraine/russische-fachkraefte-2051070) and [Russian](https://www.bundesregierung.de/breg-de/themen/deutsche-einheit/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-2052768), website aimed at Russians: https://www.make-it-in-germany.ru/

As you were planning to start a PhD you have presumably a master degree and therefore might be considered "qualified". Perhaps you can find some useful information there that allows you to find a job that pays the bill and gives you a residence permit until you can sort out PhD positions.

**3. Stuttgart University/ PhD supervisor**

- Make sure to collect as much information about your situation in writing as possible. Who made the decision not to hire you? The professor, the university or was it a blanket decision by BAFA (which I do not believe)? On which grounds? It's important to know whether you will face the same challenges at every other position you could apply for. I strongly suspect that it's the field that triggered the problems as I know several Russian scientists which are employed without problems in Germany.
- If it was the professor's decision and not that of the university: Are there any other free PhD positions in related but not security-relevant fields? Have you checked with the student advisors of the university? Might be a long shot, but who knows... Information for doctoral students [doctoral students](https://www.uni-stuttgart.de/en/research/early-career-researchers/doctoral-degree-studies/) (in English) and generally for [international students](https://www.uni-stuttgart.de/en/study/counseling/international/).
- Whether your degree itself is a problem, can be checked via the anabin database. This database allows users to check whether a given institute/university is considered an accredited university and whether a given degree has a German equivalent. The website is in German and as I don't know the official name of your degree I cannot check whether it's listed. If you want me/us to check you might want to post the name of your degree. Please note: the universities are the ones which in the end can decide whether to employ you or not; rules for universities vary from one German state to another.

**4. other German universities/ research institutes**

- Check other universities whether they have international offices which offer **fast** help for people stuck in Germany because of the current situation. Many universities started programs/stipends for helping Ukrainian students and researchers in a fast and unbureaucratic way. Some of them expand the help beyond Ukrainians to "everybody affected by the war". Again, it's a long shot, but perhaps you can find some help there.
- Another long shot, but perhaps the DAAD (German Academic Exchange Service) can advice you: https://www.daad.de/en/the-daad/information-for-russian-students-and-researchers/

**Final note:**
As you can see there is quite some information aimed directly at Russians, therefore I conclude that your nationality is not principally a problem and there is hope that with some adjustments to your original plan you might be able to make it work at a different university.

Answer (score 1):

If you went to Germany, I assume you have at least a minimum knowledge of German.

Then just move to Austria. They always had a more neutral attitude, plus it is much cheaper to live there.

Given the boundary political condition, you will probably have to deal with low-paying, low-qualified jobs, for a short or long spell of time. But Austria has a much more balanced salary-cost of life ratio. And Austira is a overlooked destination, so you will be able to find a technical job much quick there. Not ideal, but you have the knowledge to boot yourself up and become a programmer. And after a couple of years you will be able to get into a Ph.D. program.

The bottom line is: now you have to fight for your political ideas, do not expect you will always find someone supportive. You are unfortunately fighting for a repressed idea, which is "russian are humans, russian deserves some right, russian politician invaded a foreign country" and it is a very unpopular idea in the West, because the West is now thinking "Putin is a psycopathic, invading for no meaningful reason a foreign country, therefore Russia is a country of psycopathic", which has been very recently summed up by the vice-president of the European Union "we are a garden, outside there is a jungle" (Borrell, 2022 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7f_XLuiNa4).

Good luck, and enjoy the ride, your voice in the West is not censored, but unfortunately it will be voluntarily not heard.

P.s.: because of the war, you are facing these temporary issues that are preventing you from getting into your dream path. Whenever one of these temporary issues is death, the prevention from getting the dream path becomes permanently. I feel a bit for you (let's say a bit more for you than the average yemeniti and somali, because I am an horrible person), but I feel much more for all the Ukranians and the Russian being slaughtered in this proxy conflict.

Comment: If I'm correct that the field of study (quantum computing) is the real issue, not Germany, then this will help little. It is a potentially sensitive subject due to its relationship to encryption (a munition in most places, including the US).

Comment: If my social circle is any indication at all, language is not high on the list of considerations for most people who left, be it before or after the war started. It is just a "nice to have", the priorities are generally 1) Not dying 2) Not ending up in prison 3) After 1 and 2 are fulfilled for the immediate closest circle, making ends meet 4) Not being thrown too far off the chosen life path (one could become a janitor in theory, sure) 5) Other nice-to-haves. Thank you for your sympathy and yes, there are still people who have it much, much worse...

Comment: @Buffy the subject itself also a problem. Some of top scientist in quantum computing are russians (Harvard,Caltech) and there more in Europe too. I don't think anyone will close this subject to them, right? I think I could only hope that different export organizations will be more selective, why throw away good brains if you could use them+they could support Ukraine with money or help to develop quantum technologies in Ukraine. I would like to do this (I am ethnic Ukrainian) instead of dying in russian prison.

Comment: They may well have more trouble getting their research funded. You don't have to be a fanatic Putinist to spy for Russia. If someone still has family members in Russia, and got a visit with the message that it would be a shame if something where to happen to them, then few could blame her/him if (s)he would than collaborate...

Comment: @Lodinn exactly. OP is facing Point 3). Given that OP was in Germany for 3 months, so hopefully got a minimum of german classes (and german bureaucracy), but almost ended his money, it is easier to fulfill point 3) by moving to Austria. It is relatively close by and even Vienna is cheaper than Stuttgart, providing plenty of opportunities to *survive* without losing completely one's dream path.

Comment: I hear you. German prices are offset by their wages, but only if you have good job prospects. Germany just happens to be a very popular destination among Russians, all things considered (another one of my friends have moved there just this month and I can't be happier for them), so possibly hearing the stories about those who have successfully emigrated and hoping to find support among fellow expatriates and Austria gets overlooked as a result.

Comment: Quantum Computing is not **practically** related to any security considerations. The connection to Shor's algorithms and other "crypto breaking algorithms" is still a theoretical curiosity. And there is no real risk in the next decade or so for "stealing information", apart perhaps for people in Quantum experimental physics, if at all. I'd cast this treatment of the candidate as a slightly political motivated action, more than an objective cautionary measure. I would suggest the OP to search for other more welcoming country.

Comment: @Dilworth You do not actually know if Quantum Computing is the problem, the OP does not know anything except that the Professor canceled the contract, and from what was said, I suspect that a background check is needed (which makes sense) and it would take too long to complete or be too expensive (I know cases like this much before this war started). Germany already issued a visa, the OP already lives in Germany, not sure what you would mean as more welcoming country. Other countries would try to deport him to Rwanda.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, no country I know of deported Russians who are in the same situation as the OP to Rwanda. And I know for a fact that many countries are welcoming to Russians scientists in related areas to those of the OP (i.e., do not invoke espionage accusations or investigations against them; here I assume OP is not a spy). Re Quantum: I was answering others who claimed this is the OP area.

Comment: @Dilworth This is exactly my point, your claims are too generic, which countries? Do these countries issue visas inside Russia? For example the US does not issue visas inside Russia since they do not have working Embassy/Consulates, only in Warsaw. And there is always the issue of survivor bias, you only hear of the successful cases and not about the unsuccessful ones (for whatever reason). And in all cases they would go through a background check. My comment about Rwanda is to show how not welcoming some countries are to refugees. And OP was not accused of being a spy, only a background check

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do everything to prove that I am neither a spy nor dangerous in some other way.
They told you that there is an investigation against you. You did not say anything about the results. If you know them, try to prove them wrong. If they have not told you the results, this might be illegal - I am pretty sure that you have a right to know what they are holding against you. Try to find out who is responsible for this and get the details of the investigation. What do they hold against you? Can you prove them wrong?

I would also try to find other scientists from Russia who work at Stuttgart university, ideally in your field of research. Get in touch with them and tell them your story. Can you prove that you are not a part of the Putin system? Did you take part in demonstrations, do you have friends that fight for democracy? If you can convince them that you are not a spy, they can help you to find a way to solve this problem.

Even if there is no chance to get the job at Stuttgart university again, you should do everything to get rid of this accusation.

Comment: I'm afraid that's what OP should have done as soon as they heard of the investigation in the first place (which seems to be shortly after their arrival around the 1st of June or even before, "this spring"), not almost half an year later.

Comment: I see your point, but I somehwat doubt that this will solve OP's problem. As others have pointed out in other comments, when it comes to security relevant technology, it's not the only issue that someone might start a position with the intention to spy - as long a the applicant has close friends or relatives in Russia, they might just be coerced to spy, no matter whether they want to support the current Russian government. (For the record, I am completely sympathetic with OP's frustration -  I just have doubts that he currently has real chances to be allowed to work on this project.)

Comment: Besides, it is incredibly hard to actually prove. Surely, if I were to send a spy, providing them with a "proof" of persecution at home would be a non-issue? A slip of a paper about detention, a photo in the police department... Having some sort of evidence in a western-controlled medium (e.g. Facebook) might be somewhat feasible, but most Russians are not as reckless as to face jailtime for posting something in opposition on social media. And unless you have really close friends there, it is hard to expect someone sticking their neck out for a near-stranger.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is either naive or misguided, you cannot prove something that has not happened. The OP has not been accused of being a spy, there are background checks needed and maybe they did not want to perform them, the only thing that is a fact is that the contract was cancelled, you might want to fight that in courts, but it would take a lot of time/money and have very little chance of success.

Comment: Sorry everyone, investigation may be a wrong word. I believe BAFA looked at my diplomas, transcripts, previous places of study, I don't think they looked at my social media accounts or something like that.

Answer (score -5):

I've thought about my answer for a few days, it will probably be unpopular, but here goes:
What did you do while in Russia to try and keep the peace? What did you do when your country just annexed a piece of another country (the Crimean peninsula) in 2014? I assume you were "just" a student. But the country you are apparently from is an aggressor that is waging war on the civilians of the Ukraine. Germany has given many Ukranians refugee status. You left, because the sanctions are making life in Russia uncomfortable, and you were perhaps (rightly) worried that you could be conscripted into the army.

You were probably promised the position by a professor who had not checked with the university administration that new hires of Russian nationals are no longer permitted. There will be nothing much you can do about that. Russians who are already here and have jobs can, naturally, keep those jobs.
Your visa was probably contingent on you getting a job here. Since the job has disappeared, that may mean that you need to apply for refugee status, and you should have done that as soon as it was clear that you were not getting the job. As a refugee applicant, you will not be permitted to work until your status is approved. If you are found not to be a refugee, you will be sent back to Russia, or given the status of 'Duldung', being tolerated, because there is currently no air traffic between Germany and Russia. You should contact a lawyer.

The nice world that we used to have with exchange of researchers and free movement pretty much everywhere has been drastically changed by the Russian invasion of the Ukraine.

Here are some links that might help you. If you don't read German, DeepL is your friend.

- https://www.nds-fluerat.org/54499/aktuelles/flucht-aus-russland-was-wir-aktuell-sagen-koennen-23-09-2022/
- https://www.uno-fluechtlingshilfe.de/hilfe-weltweit/fluechtlingsschutz/asyl-in-deutschland
- https://eriwan.diplo.de/am-de/service/05-visa-einreise/-/2521580
- https://www.vorwaerts.de/artikel/deutschland-russischen-gefluechteten-asyl-gewaehren (from March, may be too old)

Comment: I’ve had many of the same thoughts, actually, but as an American, hesitated to express them.

Comment: You incorrectly assume that "new hires of Russian nationals are no longer permitted", this is is not correct. At some institutions a background check must be performed and it is very likely the institute did not want to do it. It is a matter of time/resources, not a blanket ban as you imply.

Comment: In 2014 OP were just starting their high school, yes. Keep in mind 2014 was much less crystal-clear domestically than internationally, too: it was still shocking for many, but they then got firsthand reports from their friends and relatives from Crimea suggesting not insignificant popular support, leaving many genuinely conflicted about the matter. Media is not to be trusted, but that were reports from people they knew personally. And as for 2022, our German colleagues were much better informed than anyone domestically, even those whose news sources were not limited to the state media.

Comment: "You left, because the sanctions are making life in Russia uncomfortable" is a little loaded, too - spring is about as early as it gets for fleeing. With the Russian government dispensing their pots of gold (which would be way better spent on developing the economy instead of waging wars, but alas), sanctions are hardly what makes the life in Russia uncomfortable even now: it is domestic policies. OP would likely have better life prospects in Russia if we are talking wealth and goods strictly and ignore the issue of personal freedoms.

Comment: People often draw parallels with German scientists fleeing in WWII - they had to make concessions, but they were able to put their skills towards what they believed to be a just cause and, eventually, live decent lives. It makes sense to not welcome them with the open arms and present with offers as good as if nothing happened, but you also certainly want to avoid not providing any viable alternative at all and make them go home disappointed and thinking "I guess my government was right all along after all, I should go work for them instead".

Comment: People from west countries that enjoying democracy and good quality of life don't understand what is it to live under tyranny and constant paranoia. I tried my best to show my negative attitude toward my government action, but resistance in the country where is government could throw you in jail just for minimal resistance, where all social networks are monitored, where even your parents hate you for your position, where country are mostly populated by people who in support of government is not really possible.

Comment: You trying to tie me with my government actions, where it is not really a government but just a mod of thieves and murderers. Actually, what are you doing right now, when your  government keep buying gas and oil from the aggressor? Please, your are not the judge and I am not in the court.

Comment: "You left, because the sanctions are making life in Russia uncomfortable, and you were perhaps (rightly) worried that you could be conscripted into the army."
You don't know why I left. Staying in the country where police stopping young people and checking their phone on the matter of antiwar information and only for repost of oppositional views you could be in jail. Also I am ethnic Ukrainian and I don't want to know if putin will start a with hunt, like hitler did with Israelites.

Comment: What about people working in the US and having research/industrial connection with Saudi Arabia? Do you have some nice words for them, too?

Comment: I deleted a snarky comment of mine since @Evgenii's comments explain much better what I consider wrong with this answer.

Comment: Evgenii, I realize it is difficult when you are personally affected by this. But you cannot expect things to remain as they were before Putin invaded. Be glad that you are out, sort out your visa (I put in some links) and find other work for now. Dr. Snoopy, we have been told that we are not allowed to hire Russian citizens. German universities are governed at state level, not federal. @Lodinn, that is an excellent point with German scientists fleeing WWII. And that was my point: he should apply for asylum, so that he has a place to stay and food until things get sorted out.

Comment: @DeboraWeber-Wulff Thank you a lot for the information, by the way - this is all very helpful. I must admit I am very conflicted about your answer: while I disagree with many of the points raised (and there's a very significant bias in my own outlook on the situation kicking in, of course), I think it is a good thing you have decided to post it. Seeing the other side of the argument is much needed, and so is learning to tackle it gracefully. The presentation seems to be the most contentious part here. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) For a person in this kind of situation, there's a world of difference between opening with "you should do X, Y and Z, it would put you in a disadvantaged position for a number of years, but opens a way forward, and there is no such thing as an easy option for you now" and "you should've done something differently in your life earlier". Even if the end result is the same, the second reads like "screw you, go figure it out". With some work on the receiving side, this advice could be used, but the kneejerk reaction for someone constantly fighting is to give up and go bang on another door.

Comment: I believe this answer is on the verge of racism or illegal discrimination (accusing someone based on their nationality without any information about them). PS, the same question could be directed to Debora: "what exactly did you do to stop the war in Ukraine? Why didn't you join US Secret Service to infiltrate Putin's Russia, for example??"

Comment: @Dilworth, um, don't you see? If he had done something and BECAUSE of that fled, it would be easier for him to obtain asylum. But even if he didn't, he can still obtain asylum, it is just more difficult. As I am no longer a US citizen, your suggestion won't work :) There are many things that can be done to help Ukranians, and what I have done or not done is not the question here. I am not accusing him of anything, I think you are mis-reading something into what I wrote. It is tragic when big plans fall through, but one needs to finde a Plan B and perhaps C.